# Can't see contents of linux file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

In Ubuntu 10.04, there is a certain file that appears highlighted in terminal. When I try to cat the file, it says there is no such file or directory. How can I see what's in this file? Is this a symbolic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's a broken symbolic link pointing to some non-existing destination file?

Some commands you might like to try:

```
ls -la /path/to/your/file
stat /path/to/your/file
file /path/to/your/file
```